# In comment, the site silently transforms non-breaking space into normal space

Tags: bug, comments

In a comment, the site silently transforms non-breaking space into normal space. I don't like this. This gives bad typography. Like here in my comment : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10055337/1824094

Comment: I think that's by design to avoid abuse of non-breaking spaces. At least I vaguely remember reading that somewhere.

Comment: In general comments are given only the most limited formatting options to be functional.

Comment: If you . . . . . . need it            there are options (Hint: 205F)

Comment: Comments are supposed to be transitory - if they contain important information they should be rolled into the post they are on. And at that point, they can go away. Trying to put so much effort into a comment is counter productive.

Comment: @brasofilo and if you abuse it, I'm sure we can update our filter... ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell, yups, no abuse meant. I'd rather stick . . . . . to dots ;)

Comment: @Joachim — In this case, it would be nice to transform the abuse without transforming the correct use.

Comment: brasofilo - Dukeling —  I  don't  get  your  workarounds.  And that's too bad that I cannot put the two "@" here.

Comment: @Oded But it is nice to not have a short piece of code wrap in the middle (and it's not *that* much effort if you have a program that does it for you).